# Add Docker Machine to Swarm cluster after creation

Tags: docker

A Docker Swarm cluster can be created as:

```
docker-machine create \
               -d virtualbox --virtualbox-disk-size "5000" \
               --swarm --swarm-master \
               --swarm-discovery="consul://$(docker-machine ip consul-machine):8500" \
               --engine-opt="cluster-store=consul://$(docker-machine ip consul-machine):8500" \
               --engine-opt="cluster-advertise=eth1:2376" swarm-master
docker-machine create \
               -d virtualbox --virtualbox-disk-size "5000" \
               --swarm \
               --swarm-discovery="consul://$(docker-machine ip consul-machine):8500" \
               --engine-opt="cluster-store=consul://$(docker-machine ip consul-machine):8500" \
               --engine-opt="cluster-advertise=eth1:2376" swarm-node-01
docker-machine create \
               -d virtualbox --virtualbox-disk-size "5000" \
               --swarm \
               --swarm-discovery="consul://$(docker-machine ip consul-machine):8500" \
               --engine-opt="cluster-store=consul://$(docker-machine ip consul-machine):8500" \
               --engine-opt="cluster-advertise=eth1:2376" swarm-node-02
```

These machines join the Swarm cluster during creation itself. If a new Docker Machine is created as:

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-disk-size "5000" swarm-node-03
```

How can this machine be configured later to be part of the same Swarm cluster?

Comment: You will need to fire manually the Swarm containers (agents and etc) inside that machine.

Comment: See the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/install-manual/#create-swarm-nodes) for installing and joining nodes manually to a Swarm.

Answer (score 2):

It's not configurable directly through Machine today, but you could run the Swarm containers manually on the created instance.  Running `docker ps --no-trunc` and taking a look at a joined Swarm container should show you the command you need to launch.

The trickiest bit is probably making sure that TLS is configured correctly.  My suggestion would be to use `docker-machine scp` to sync the certficates you need from one of the already running Swarm hosts to another.

In the future, I'm hopeful that we can split out the bits in Machine which "orchestrate Swarm" into some smaller pieces so that this type of use case is easier.

**UPDATE**: Looks slightly easier than I had realized.  No need to manually copy certs.  In your case I think something like the following command should join the machine to an existing Swarm:

```
$ docker \
    $(docker-machine config swarm-node-03) \
    run -d swarm \
    join --advertise $(docker-machine ip swarm-node-03) --discovery="consul://$(docker-machine ip consul-machine):8500"
```

It should now be visible in the Swarm master's `docker info`.

Comment: docker info still showing the same set of nodes even after the command. Is --cluster-advertise replaced by --advertise? No need to specify --cluster-store?

Comment: Shouldn't need to set `--cluster-store`, I think that's for the Docker daemon.  `--advertise` (with an argument) should work for an invoked `swarm` command.

Comment: Something is still amiss as exactly repeating these steps is not updating `docker info` output for me. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried to edit the docker config file to adjust the engine options, adding cluster-store and cluster-advertise params, restarting the docker daemon inside the machine, and then adding the swarm *join* container?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
docker \
  $(docker-machine config swarm-node-03) \
  run -d swarm join --addr $(docker-machine ip swarm-node-03):2376 \
  consul://$(docker-machine ip consul-machine):8500
```